# In Excel, how can I make a table with columns based on a row of another table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in Excel like this:

| Part Number | Cost | Where Used | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | $0.05 | Widget | Screw |
| 1001 | $2.00 | Widget | Housing |
| 1002 | $5.50 | Widget | Circuit Board |
| 1003 | $1.00 | Gismo | Display |
| 1004 | $0.75 | Gismo | Gasket |
| 1005 | $0.23 | Thing | Speaker |
| 1006 | $0.12 | Gismo | Membrane |
| 1007 | $2.43 | Widget | Motor |

I want to create second table, where the columns are dynamically created from the third row in the first table, and the values are taken from the fourth column:

| Widget | Gizmo | Thing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Screw | Display | Speaker |
| Housing | Gasket |  |
| Circuit Board | Membrane |  |
| Motor |  |  |

Is there a way to make Excel do this without a macro?

Comment: You can use FILTER function to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use a formula like: `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE("where used"))` to dynamically generate your headers,

then use a formula like: `=FILTER("description", "where used"="headers generated with first formula")` to dynamically generate the table body

the description and where used in the second filter should be anchored so that dragging the formula across will get all of the data per column

for example: [image]

will get you this: [image]

I'm sure there are other ways to do it.